# How to evaluate the following limit of integral?

Tags: calculus, limits

If $$A_n = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{dt}{(1+t)^n}$$ Then i have to find out $$\lim_{n \to \infty} A_n^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

For $n \neq 1$, $$A_n = \frac{1}{(1-n)2^{n-1}} + \frac{1}{n-1}$$ Then what is the value of $$\lim_{n \to \infty} A_n^{\frac{1}{n}}$$?

Comment: Is $t > 0$ ? can you clarify ...?

Comment: Yes it is in between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Why does your $A_n$ have a $t$?

Comment: I am sorry, i have made the change.

Comment: This limit is of the indeterminate $0^0$. Does that give any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as, for $n \gt 1$
$$
A_n = \frac1{n-1}\bigg(1-\frac1{2^{n-1}} \bigg)
$$
we may write
$$
\frac1{n-1} \gt A_n \gt \frac1{2(n-1)}
$$
which, since $2^{\frac1n} \to 1$ shows
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \bigg(A_n\bigg)^{\frac1n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} (n-1)^{-\frac1n} = 1
$$
the last equality follows from $1 \gt  (n-1)^{-\frac1n} \gt n^{-\frac1n}$ together with
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log n}n = 0
$$
whose truth can be seen from the fact that
$$
\frac{\frac{\log n^k}{n^k}}{\frac{\log n}{n}}=\frac{ k}{n^{k-1}}
$$

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: You need to rewrite it as $\left(1-n\right)^{-1/n}\cdot \left(\dfrac{1}{2^{n-1}}+1\right)^{1/n}$. For the first factor simply write the base as $n\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)$, and upon taking the $
n$-th root, and take limit it goes to $1$, and the second factor also goes to $1$ which is not that hard to manipulate. So the product goes to ?

Comment: The first factor does not  have to do with $e$. You are thinking (as I did the first time I worked on this) of $(1-1/n)^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Check your result:

$\begin{array}\\
A_n 
&= \int_{0}^{1}\frac{dt}{(1+t)^n}\\
&= \int_{0}^{1}(1+t)^{-n}dt\\
&=\dfrac{(1+t)^{-n+1}}{-n+1}\big|_0^1\\
&=-\dfrac{(1+t)^{-n+1}}{n-1}\big|_0^1\\
&=-(\dfrac{2^{-n+1}}{n-1}-\dfrac{1}{n-1})\\
&=\frac1{n-1}(1-2^{-n+1})\\
\text{so}\\
A_n^{1/n}
&=\frac1{(n-1)^{1/n}}(1-2^{-n+1})^{1/n}\\
&=\frac1{e^{\ln(n-1)/n}}e^{\ln(1-2^{-n+1})/n}\\
&\approx \frac1{1+\ln(n-1)/n}e^{-2^{-n+1}/n}
\qquad\text{for large }n\\
&\approx(1-2^{-n+1}/n)\\
&\approx 1\\
\end{array}
$